# Is my From-Scratch system using fstab?

Tags: linux, fstab, proc

I've started writing a simple, small distro, not using LFS. Everything has been going amazingly smooth so far. I only have one problem, which I address here - whenever I boot up, my system is "read-only". I've found out that I can fix this by:

```
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Essentially mounting `/proc` and remounting `/`. Before I run these commands, `/proc` is not a regular proc directory - it contains one or two things.

Now, my `fstab` is the following:

```
# file system  mount-point  type   options          dump  fsck
#                                                         order

rootfs         /            auto   defaults         1     1
proc           /proc        proc   defaults         0     0
sysfs          /sys         sysfs  defaults         0     0
devpts         /dev/pts     devpts gid=4,mode=620   0     0
tmpfs          /dev/shm     tmpfs  defaults         0     0
```

And it seems like this is valid. Furthermore, my system is booting up, meaning it's gotta have read the fstab, right? But, `proc` isn't valid before running this command...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SysVInit or Systemd?

Comment: @rfmodulator BusyBox init ;)

Comment: If you don't pass `ro` on the kernel command line, then it *should* default to `rw` ...otherwise, it's the responsibility of your `init` to re-mount the root fs as `rw` (if so configured). I can't help with you BusyBox specifically, but the init scripts are a good place to start looking.

Comment: @rfmodulator well, I don't even touch the kernel command line ;). I believe the reason it's switching to ro because `/proc` doesn't mount correctly - I have to mount it manually, then update to rw. I'd like to know why /proc isn't being mounted well :).

Comment: I can see now that my previous comment is confusing, what I mean is the kernel will default to `rw` if `ro` is not provided. But `grub` passes `ro` to the kernel by default. You can check it with `dmesg | grep -i command`, or now that you have mounted `/proc`, you can do `cat /proc/cmdline`. `init` is responsible for processing `/etc/fstab`. A read write root fs doesn't depend on `/proc`.

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much! Turns out you were correct - grub is passing `ro` to the kernel. Changed it to rw, and boom - done! Also fixed another problem I had with grub. Thanks again!

Comment: @rfmodulator whoops - my bad. Though my other grub problem is fixed, it's still readonly. Trying out the other commands now - meanwhile, let's move this to a chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113799/discussion-between-bobbay-and-rfmodulator).

Comment: Persistence depends on *where* you changed `ro` to `rw`... but I think from here you need to troubleshoot your BusyBox init... the correct answer to both of your issues (`rw` root fs and auto mount /proc) is going to rely on that. Telling the kernel to mount `ro` then allowing `init` to handle it from there isn't a bad plan. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks! I was able to figure it out - answers in the chat. Thank you for your help!